# FIGMA- What is the shortcut keyboard button for adding stroke to a Line?

Tags: figma, figma-api

FIGMA- What is the shortcut keyboard button for adding stroke to a Line? How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

I think we have to that manually itself. Perhaps, there's no short key for adding a stroke to a Line.